# Flask global login for middleware WSGI apps that start in main thread

Tags: python, flask, middleware, flask-login, werkzeug

In my flask app, I have another WSGI app that needs to be started in the main thread. I have login required check in my other end points, however, the WSGI middleware app can be accessed using it's endpoint without logging in. Any way to enforce login to be able access the middleware app?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
import flask
import os
import logging
import functools
import tensorboard as tb
from werkzeug import serving
from werkzeug.middleware import dispatcher


# Log transport
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8080
USERS = {"user": ("user", "xxx")}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "yyy"

def login_required(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def secure_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if "username" not in session:
            return redirect(url_for("login", next=request.url))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return secure_function


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        if username in USERS and USERS[username][1] == password:
            session["username"] = username
            return redirect("http://%s:%s/tensorboard/" % (HOST, PORT))
    return render_template("login.html")

# tensorboard server that needs to be started in main thread
class CustomServer(tb.program.TensorBoardServer):
    def __init__(self, tensorboard_app, flags):
        del flags  # unused
        self._app = dispatcher.DispatcherMiddleware(
            app, {"/tensorboard": tensorboard_app}
        ) # how to include login_required? 

    def serve_forever(self):
        serving.run_simple(HOST, PORT, self._app)

    def get_url(self):
        return "http://%s:%s" % (HOST, PORT)

    def print_serving_message(self):
        pass  # Werkzeug's `serving.run_simple` handles this

def start_tensorboard():
    program = tb.program.TensorBoard(server_class=CustomServer)
    program.configure(logdir="tensorboard_data/")
    program.main()

def main():
    start_tensorboard()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you looked at Flask-Security or Flask-JWT-Extended module instead of implementing your own? Basically just need to add \@login_required or \@jwt_required respectively on method that requires login

Comment: I do have the login_required decorator implemented. It's working for other functions. But I don't know how to enforce login_required in the middleware WSGI app.